# What can I substitute for Gruyère in quiche lorràine?

Tags: substitutions, cheese, quiche

Gruyère cheese is too expensive here and I want make quiche lorràine. Is there some other cheese that I could substitute for the gruyère that would preserve the original flavor?

Comment: As your profile mentions Brazil ... I'm not familiar with their cheeses, but a little research seems to be pointing me to either *queijo minas curado* (or maybe *meia-cura*) or  *queijo de colônia*.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple variations that if you're lucky might be cheaper: Beaufort and Comté. (I've only actually tried Comté, but I've seen Beaufort listed along with it and Gruyère.)

A bit farther away are Emmentaler and Jarlsberg. They both have the Swiss cheese flavor but aren't quite as firm nicely aged. Beyond that there's simply all the varieties of (American) Swiss cheese, which are generally roughly like Emmanteler but likely even softer.

If you use one of the farther away substitutes, I'd suggest adding in some hard aged cheese as well to make up for the difference. For example, I've used (American) Swiss cheese plus dry jack and parmesan and been pretty happy with it. The specific hard aged cheese probably doesn't matter a whole lot, as long as it has some nice aged flavor and not a lot of overpowering other flavors.

Comment: Gruyere is pretty expensive here as well. It's about 4x the cost of jarlsberg which is a household favorite in my house. Most recipes that have called for a large amount of cheese, I have used jarlsberg as the substitute. The cheese closest to the rind is nice and firm. Not as hard as Gruyere, but harder than the nice soft interior of the wheel.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be faithful to the French terminology, a *quiche (lorraine)* does not contain cheese. Ever. It's not even a matter of being "classic" or  "authentic", putting cheese on a *tarte* is very common, but it's just called differently if you do (namely *tarte*). Have you ever tried an actual French *quiche* (i.e. without cheese)? Maybe you will like it.

Alternatively, you can put just about any cheese on it. Results will differ, hard somewhat aged cow-milk cheese like those suggested by @Jefromi will be closest to gruyère but anything goes really: Dutch cheese, soft cheese like maroilles or munster, blue cheese, goat cheese, feta cheese, feel free to experiment with what's available where you are.

Incidentally, if anything, I think it's actually more common to add a relatively bland, creamy cheese like emmentaler rather than a stronger older cheese to a *tarte* so there is no reason to consider the latter as *the* ingredient to be substituted or a *tarte* with gruyère as the "original flavor" to aim for.

Now if you like that and want to do it on the cheap, then maybe comté or beaufort are not very good options, as they might be just as expensive and possibly harder to find. I would try to look for an aged Dutch-like cheese (locally produced Gouda imitation or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

You could just find a recipe that doesn't use it. Classic quiche Lorraine does not contain cheese.

Comment: According to Julia Child's Mastering the Art of French cooking, "the classic quiche Lorraine contains heavy cream, eggs and bacon, no cheese."

Comment: That may be true but if the op wants to make a specific recipe that does call for cheese, it's irrelevant that you have a version that doesn't.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=classic+quiche+Lorraine+does+NOT+contain+cheese&oq=classic+quiche+Lorraine+does+NOT+contain+cheese&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 The "classic" is unknown. Several world-renowned chefs use cheese today.

Comment: Just because some chefs have decided to add the cheese, it doesn't mean that all recipes have to have it. I can't say which version is more "classic", but cheeseless Lorraine is quite normal for me.