# Cheaper Gruyere Substitute for baking Cheese Puffs in Australia

Tags: baking, substitutions, cheese

I live in Australia and what is a cheaper substitute for Gruyere Cheese for baking cheese puffs?

Comment: Here's some ideas to replace the gruyere cheese on quiche lorraine, I believe it can be useful: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/63770/what-can-i-substitute-for-gruy%c3%a8re-in-quiche-lorr%c3%a0ine

Answer (score 2):

I do love gougères and have made them with Gruyere, of course, but have also used regular Swiss and a favorite, provolone. Other cheeses that melt well and you could try are Fontina, Gouda, or good old cheddar.